# How to Submit only after Jquery finished updating the field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where a user inputs a word, when pressing the button I want it to translate the word (using the jquery script) into the same field. 
Only after completed to populate the field, it should continue and submit the translated word.

everything is working except that it will submit as soon as it translating causing the original word to be submitted instead of the translated one.
the original page shows that the word had been translated.

please help on how to make it submit only after the word have been translated in the text field. ? 
should I use a delay ? if so how ?
or is there an oncomplete, "onpopulate" or something like that ?

here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(function transle() {  
    $('#transbox').sundayMorningReset();
    $('#transbox  input[type=submit]').click(function(evt) {
        $.sundayMorning(
          $('#transbox input[type=text]').val(),
            { source:'', destination:'ZH', menuLeft:evt.pageX, menuTop:evt.pageY},
               function(response) {
                    $('#transbox input[type=text]').val(response.translation);                      
                }
        );

    });             
});

</script>
```

and the form:

```
 <table id="transbox" width="30px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <form action="custom-page" method="get" name="form1" target="_blank" id="form1" >
         <tr>
             <td><input  id="q" name="q" type="text" class="search_input" value="Evening dress" /></td>
             <td><input type="submit" /></td>
         </tr>
     </form>
 </table>
```

there are another JS called for the script but I don't sure its needed for the question.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` and after filling call `submit` event of your form

```
function(response) {
      $('#transbox input[type=text]').val(response.translation);
      document.forms.form1.submit();
}

<input type="button" />
```

Comment: Tried that, problem it does not submit.

Comment: the js being used is: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
maybe this is the reason ?

Comment: it doesn't matter which version of jquery you use check it again with the old version http://jsfiddle.net/926HC/5/

Comment: Ok, it works in chrome and not in firefox... strange, in chrome it ask me if i'm sure i want to open a popup , firefox just translate without opening. IE also warns about popup...

Comment: replace `form1.submit();` by `document.forms.form1.submit();`

Comment: Hi thank you, I have just replaced to : document.getElementById("form1").submit(); before I saw your post and it works in firefox. now I just need to figure out why all browsers treat it like a popup, when the action is from the jquery... any thoughts ?

Comment: it is not popup, in your form tag you used `target="_blank"` that open new window remove it to open the form in the same window

Comment: Hi, I do want it to open in a new window, but when in submited via jquery it seems to take it as popup. is there a way to still open it in a new page ?

Comment: really I don't know why it be opened as popup but I am sure it isn't jquery issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.
 I will try make another question for that one.